# Using a variable to reference tables/collections, using Remove() function

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I'm making an app that has multiple units where you can view the technology/machines associated with them. You can also edit the information, delete machines, and make logs for them. **I'm using Excel data with a canvas app.**

The user picks the unit, then the machine within the unit, and then they can view the information or edit it. So far, I've been able to get by with having the user pick their table first, which then causes the app to present information for that assigned variable throughout the rest of the app. (For example, a gallery is not assigned to a specific table, but assigned to a variable that changes depending on user input).

A part of OnStart looks like this:

```
Set(UnitChoice, table_newunit);
```

And an example of a command with a business unit (The user presses a button).
OnSelect for a business unit looks like this:

```
Navigate('MACHINE SCREEN');
Set(UnitChoice, tb_axle);
```

`tb_axle` is one of the business tables. This goes on for multiple tables, such as `tb_rail`, `tb_paint`, etc.

Now onto the problem. When you get to the 'MACHINE SCREEN', I wanted to give the option of deleting a machine.

I thought the remove function would be proper. I made a pop-up container, and it gives the user a confirmation dialogue for the deletion. Here's what I got:

```
Remove(UnitChoice, gallery_machines.Selected);
Refresh(UnitChoice);
Navigate(screen_success)
```

I get an error message that says the first argument should be a collection, so I'm guessing the variable trick won't work in this case? I wanted to make it simple, but I could 1000% do an IF statement for each unit based on what choice the user made. However there's enough tables to the point where that would be a bit of a hassle. I wanted this to be adaptable for when the users add more units. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So UnitChoice is set to the full table.  I think you would need to filter it and add it to a collection, then use that in the Remove.

Comment: Agreeing with @HSS. Using Set() you create a table variable not a collection.

Answer (score 0):

For the collection vs table error see the comments.

However, at the start of your post you say deleting machines is one of the functionalities of your app.
Bear in mind, that if you use Set(), Table() or Collect() you will create a copy of the data inside the app, not a reference. If you then use Remove() you only delete the data from the copied data, not from your Excel data source. So, you might want to use the function like this `Remove(tb_axle,gallery_machines.Selected)`

Also, the Remove() function will automatically refresh the tb_axle data in your app, no need to call Refresh(). Refresh() by the way will also not accept any collection/table variable as argument, only data sources. To keep your UnitChoice variable in sync, you will need to assign it again.